# A delivery counter which excludes sunday and holidays

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, counter

I'm using a delivery Day counter to show my customers on which day they can expect their package.
But... there is a problem.
The delivery days should be (the day ordered + 2 days (before 12 o clock(germany)) if not 3 days)that's working like a charme. But I can't get my head aroung excluding sundays. At the moment the counter adds one day if it is sunday... But for example if it is saturday the counter doesn't add a day (for the nonDeliveryDate)

atm (after 12 o' clock):

17.09.2020 - delivery to Monday = right

18.09.2020 - delivery to Monday = wrong (should be Tuesday)

19.09.2020 - delivery to Tuesday = wrong (should be Wednesday)

20.09.2020 - delivery to Wednesday = right

I think the problem is that the counter only adds one day if "today" is sunday but not if one of the next 3 days is sunday... but i'm not really sure how to solve that.

That's my script:

```html
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(function($) {
        // Current date/time
        var now = new Date();
        // Placeholder for delivery time
        var deliveryDate;
        // Amount of days to deliver
        var deliveryDays = 2;
        // Working hours (in UTC -1)
        var workingHours = [0 , 9];

        // Non-delivery days/dates
        // Must match the format returned by .toString(): 
        // Mon Sep 28 1998 14:36:22 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
        var nonDelivery = [
            "Sun",
            "Dec 24",
            "Dec 25",
            "Dec 31",
            "Jan 1"
        ];

        // Create a regular expression
        var rxp = new RegExp(nonDelivery.join("|"));

        // addDay holds the amount of days to add to delivery date
        var addDay = deliveryDays;

        // Add an extra day if outside of working hours
        var currentHour = now.getUTCHours();
        if (currentHour < workingHours[0] || 
            currentHour > workingHours[1]) {
            addDay++;
        }

        // Create our delivery date
        while (!deliveryDate) {
            // Add day(s) to delivery date
            now.setDate(
                now.getDate() + addDay
            );
            deliveryDate = now;
            if (rxp.test(deliveryDate)) {
                addDay = 1;
                deliveryDate = false;
            }
        }

        // Format
        var locale = "de-DE"; // Our locale
        //  var day = deliveryDate.toLocaleDateString(locale, { day: "numeric" });
        var weekday = deliveryDate.toLocaleDateString(locale, { weekday: "long" });
        $('#countdownDate').html( weekday + " " );            
        });
  </script>
```

Hopefully someone can help me with that...
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Given that you have other nonDelivery dates to exclude and, assuming these are also to be skipped like Sundays (rather than just next available date), then you might be better off stepping through the days - ie rather than add 2 days, add 1 day twice, each time checking if it's a non-delivery day and skipping (adding another day) if it is

Comment: so you got the solution?

Comment: Yes, made it like @freedomn-m said.. instead of adding one time 2 days I've added one day, checked if it's a nondeliverday and then added another... Simple ^^